# update-database error - NuGet Package (EntityFramework.SqlMigrations)

Tags: entity-framework, nuget-package, entity-framework-migrations

i installed EntityFramework.SqlMigrations NuGet Package 
and i get this error .
it worked for me in the past and somehow, now it does not work.

```
PM> update-database
The term 'update-database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:16
+ update-database <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (update-database:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Occurs with **EF5 RTM, VS2012 RTM**.

I experienced this problem today. I executed "Update-Package EntityFramework" in the PM Console. No changes were reported by NuGet and the problem persisted. I then restarted VS2012 and re-attempted Update-Database and it worked as expected. It's not clear what caused this problem, it's also not clear whether the Update-Package contributed to correcting it or not.

First try restarting Visual Studio, then try Update-Package EntityFramework followed by a restart.

Comment: +1, restarting did the trick, so it looks like `Update-Package EntityFramework` isn't needed.

Comment: I think people are experiencing two different problems that manifest the same way. Some people actually need to force a package update (poorly managed solutions pulled fresh from source control with lingering EF artifacts, for example)  and others are finding a bug where the PM console doesn't properly init the EF modules/cmdlets.

Answer (score 3):

I just used this command:

```
Update-Package EntityFramework -Reinstall
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, helped installing EntityFramework package first:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

and then installing EntityFramework.Migrations again:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework.Migrations
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem for me. Additionally, the package "EntityFramework.Migrations" is no longer published so this solution may have only been valid for "5.0-pre" packages.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but to get it to work again I had to re-install the EntityFramework.Migrations package. After it had reapplied the Init.ps1 it remembered all the commands.

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything else, the only way I could get my EntityFramework Migrations commands back was to run the following from the "Package Manager Console":

```
Import-Module \*PathToSolution*\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0-beta2\tools\EntityFramework.psd1
```

After running the above, Add-Migration, Update-Database, etc. was available again.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Visual Studio solved the problem for me...

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was the **Nuget version**.

1. uninstall Nuget Package Manager.
2. restart Visual Studio.
3. installed new version of Nuget Package Manager.
4. then re-start Visual Studio again