# The EntityFramework package is not installed on project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, nuget-package

I am having trouble getting the EF to install on my very simple project called 'Match' (just now learning MVC, better late than never).  The general context here is that I created the Model class with only 2 fields and now I want to change the Model class to have a few more fields/properties. I have made the change in the Model class and am now trying to update the DB to match. I am trying to use Update-Database from EF to do that.

> PM> install-package EntityFramework
>   You are downloading EntityFramework from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=253898&clcid=0x409. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
>   Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.
>   Successfully added 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' to Match.
>
> Type 'get-help EntityFramework' to see all available Entity Framework commands.
>
> PM> Enable-Migrations
>   Get-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ProjectName'.
>   At C:\Users\Dave\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Match\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:611 char:40
>   + $package = Get-Package -ProjectName <<<< $project.FullName | ?{ $_.Id -eq 'EntityFramework' }
>   + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Package], ParameterBindingException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.GetPackageCommand
>
> The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'Match'.

Comment: Do you work model-first or code-first? What command do you use to update the database?

Comment: Is this only related to this project? Can you add EF to other projects?

Comment: Found a similar problem in this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7873572/461958. See if that helps. If so, this cab be marked as a duplicate post.

Comment: I am using a code first model. 
For some reason, it started working when I removed the entity framework package i Installed using GUI version of the package manager (which installs version 5.0.0) and installed version 4.3.1 using the console instead

Comment: In my case, I have installed package that caused to issues in dependencies. When I remove that it works perfectly

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just update NuGet to 2.x. EF 5.0 requires it.

Answer (score 241):

Hopefully no-one is as stupid as me, but for the benefit of searchers:

One possibility for this error - In the Package Manager Console, there is a dropdown for 'Default Project'. If this is set incorrectly, you will get The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'x'. Change the dropdown to your EF project and all is good again.

Comment: This was the problem for me, but the drop down was empty until I restarted VS.

Comment: Changing visual studio versions sets the default project to ' ' (nothing) it seems. This fixed it for me too.

Comment: I know this is a little older, but you can also just add -ProjectName "EFProject" to the command in package manager

Answer (score 102):

In my case, restarting the Visual Studio helped.

Comment: This actually fixed it for me so I would disagree and say this is one of many potential answers to the question.

Comment: did not think that this helps, but I tried it and it has resolved the problem.

Comment: agh thought it was the .netcore upgrade the error message was `Update-Database : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'c' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: `...

Comment: I did not expect this but it did work.  Nothing else worked and everything else was set properly and set the same after closing and reopening.

Comment: The "update-database" command had been working fine for a week or more, then today it stopped working with this error. Restarting VS worked for me, the only thing I'd done in between was to add an Azure publish profile and kick off a publish.

Comment: This solves 99% of issues you face, you just need to remember that

Answer (score 13):

I have just restarted Visual Studio and it worked.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package in my project! problem fixed.

Comment: this was it for me

Answer (score 8):

In my case I had a project that for some reason did not have a Packages.config file. The result was I got the error mesage "The EntityFramework package is not installed on project xxxx".

To solve this simply add a Packages.config file and "Install-Package EntityFramework" then works.

Answer (score 7):

In my projects I installed EntityFramework on them separately. Even though they all had the same version numbers on each project, it still didn't work. Resulting in the same error you get.

To fix this, I removed EntityFramework from all my projects and reinstalled it again.

```
Get-Project -all | Uninstall-Package EntityFramework
```

Next, you just reinstall it again.

```
Get-Project -all | Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Comment: In my case I did the uninstall step and then reinstalled Entity only on the project I have the DbContext.

Answer (score 5):

I have experienced with that issue I solved it by just install **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools** nuget package

that package will Enable these commonly used commands:
Add-Migration
Drop-Database
Get-DbContext
Get-Migration
Remove-Migration
Scaffold-DbContext
Script-Migration
Update-Database

Comment: this sometimes fixes it for me and sometimes does not..

Comment: restarting VS fixed it...

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem.
I have added EFCore to a project that has installed EF6.
so add-migration xx command performed with EF6 instated of EFCore and I get this error.
removing EF6 and restarting Visual Studio solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to install the EF into your project. You can do that via Tools|Manage NuGet Packages, look under 'Installed' and click on 'Manage'. There you will see an option to install EF in your project. After that everything should work and modelchanges will be possible.
It can take quite some time (in my case, it did!).
Success!
Peter

Answer (score 3):

Open package manager console and select default project from dropdown in package manager console And Install entity framework using this command in command window.

```
install-Package Entityframework
```

Answer (score 3):

In My Case reinstall Entity Package and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: saved my day Maryam

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the Entity Framework Package, from the Nuget Package Manager of your project, that's solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the packages.config file was on disk but not in TFS.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen if the Entity Framework command's target project is unloaded in the Visual Studio solution (i.e. if you'd previously right-clicked the project in Solution Explorer and selected "Unload Project").

In this case, the solution is to load the project, then try running the Entity Framework command again.

Answer (score 0):

should work if you are opening a project for the first time,

second click  on the console project and  "Set as stratup project"

Answer (score 0):

install 
EntityFrameworkCore
install 
EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
And Then Close Visual Studio And reopen 
Problem Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can also clear cache NuGet in VS. resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a Xamarin.Forms solution with three projects - Backend (for Azure Database connection), one common library, an iOS project and an Android project. The error messages that I have received were *"The EntityFramework package is not installed on project ..."* and *"No context type was found in the assembly ..."*. I have solved it by setting Backend as my StartUp project and then by entering the commands in the following format in the Package Manager Console:

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName Backend -Verbose
```

and after that

```
add-migration -ProjectName Backend Initial
```

I hope that this is of help for someone :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be related with conflict of two versions of EntityFramework and EntityFrameworkCore. For checking it, you can write: `Get-Module` in package manager console. If you see EntityFramework and EntityFrameworkCore together, you need to delete EntityFramework or dependecy that linked on EntityFramework. For searching dependency you can use search solution input in solution explorer. After deleting dependency or EntityFramework you need to restart project.

Answer (score 0):

I will also add that closing and opening Visual Studio solves this problem for me. As of the time of writing this, this issue occurs on Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Entityframework and Entityframeworkcore may conflict and cause this; Explicit call may avoid the issue. Try enter the following in package manager console.

```
dotnet ef database update --project ./WebAPI
```