# Unable to Install "Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations" using Packag Manager console

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, console, migration, nuget-package

I'm trying to install the `Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations` using Package Manager Console to enable migrations for my context.

But, It's giving error like as follows:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations
Get-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ProjectName'.
At D:\Projects\MVC\WITL CMS\CmsV1.0\WCMS\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:611 char:40
+     $package = Get-Package -ProjectName <<<<  $project.FullName | ?{ $_.Id -eq 'EntityFramework' }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Package], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.GetPackageCommand

The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'WCMS'.
```

My Entity Framework Version is 5.0

How to solve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The EntityFramework package is not installed on project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923077/the-entityframework-package-is-not-installed-on-project)

Answer (score 0):

As it says "The EntityFramework package **is not installed** on project 'WCMS'.". Do you have other projects in the solution? If so, pay attention to the second combo box in **PM Console** which allows for selecting the project to which you apply the changes, that is, the one which has EntityFramework installed.

Also, you say you have EF 5.0 installed. Automatic migrations (not code-first ones) come with EF 6.x. *Although I'm not absolutely sure about EF version, unless you have some really important reasons to stick to EF 5.0 it is better to upgrade to 6.x.* Just use Nuget.

Anyway, first of all check the correct **ProjectName** in the **PM console**.