# How to use Entity framework install on another project in one solution

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using Code-First approach of EntityFramework in Windows Form Application

I have two projects: One for forms and the other for classes(ClassLibrary)

I have created models with context class and mapped them to database.

Then I had to change my model and do migration.

I tried to enable it:

```
Enable-Migrations
```

and got this error:

```
The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'ClassLibrary'.
```

I tried referencing entityframework from my ClassLibrary but it did not help.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What EF version are you using?

Comment: I am using EF 6.0.0.0

Comment: Did you already read this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923077/the-entityframework-package-is-not-installed-on-project)?

Comment: @Odrai I read the accepted answer which did not help me. After your suggestion, I looked at other answers then I found the right thing to do. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install via Nuget. Just install EF in the second project