# The EntityFramework package is not installed on project even though it is

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I first had this issue after new version of EntityFramework came out. It says I could not Add-Migration because `The EntityFramework package is not installed on project` . Now before links [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923077/the-entityframework-package-is-not-installed-on-project). It's not that - see below:

[image]

And it is absolutely installed:

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Expressions" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Discounted.Models\Discounted.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I originally fixed this issue by updating the packages.

I have tried:

- Rebuilding/Cleaning as well as
- Deleting the the obj & bin folders
- Restoring the the Project & Solution

Comment: @Michael I don't run my migrations assembly from that project - no need to have it installed in the project, only in the same project as your entry point.

Comment: The error is strange and seems to come from "classic" Entity Framework (EF6) rather than EF Core 6.0. Try `Get-Help Add-Migration` and see what it outputs.

Comment: @IvanStoev as it turns out I had both Core and normal EF installed at some point. After uninstalling it the error still persisted until I restarted the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was two versions of Entity Framework Installed. After uninstalling the regular EF I had to restart visual studio to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my God I Solved It....In **Visual Studio 2022**
, you must Install NGet Packages are important .

### NUGET Packages

1. EntityFramework - Version 6.4.4 .
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore - Version 6.0.11.
3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational - Version 6.0.11
4. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer - Version 6.0.11
5. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design - Version 6.0.11
6. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools - Version 6.0.11

I used code first approach ... **My Error**

[image]

**Follow ME:**

```
PM> EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration
cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: "Initial-Migraion"
```

[image]

```
PM> EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database
Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework6\Update-Database' for Entity Framework 6.
Build started...
Build succeeded
```

[image]

.